# How do you replace specific values of a vector in R?

Tags: r, vector

I've been looking for a function that replaces specific values of a vector. For example, you have a character vector including the values `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `NA`, and you want to replace `A` with `E` and `NA` with `F`.

I've tried to write a function and came up with the below. It seems to work OK, but has problems, including that it turns factors into characters.

```
recode <- function(x, old, new) {
    u <- rep(NA, length(x))
    for (i in 1:length(old)) {
        if(is.na(old[i])) {
            u[is.na(x)] <- new[i]
        } else {
        u[x == old[i]] <- new[i]
        }
    }
    return(ifelse(x %in% old, u, x))
}
```

For example:

```
a <- sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", NA), 20, replace = T)
recode(a, old = c("A", NA), new = c("E", "F"))
```

Perhaps there is already a function that does this and I just haven't found it! Or does anyone know a sensible way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `dplyr::recode` in the newer version of `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

a <- sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", NA), 20, replace = T)
recode(a, A = "E", .missing = "F")
```

Note that there is also `dplyr::recode_factor`, which has a couple of factor-specific features (maintains order).

Comment: Thanks Michael - that's exactly what I was looking for.